# C++0x issue on ICC compilation

Tags: c++, c++11, icc

```
for each (auto obs in observers)
     *obs = true;
```

i have problem with this compiling with icc.

```
error : cannot deduce "auto" type (initializer required)
```

please help to solve the above issue. thanks.

Answer (score 10):

This syntax is not valid in C++. Try this instead:

```
for (auto obs_iter=observers.begin(); obs_iter != observers.end(); ++obs_iter)
    **obs_iter = true;
```

(This assumes that `observers` store pointers to objects)

If your compiler supports range-based for loops, you can do the following:

```
for (auto &obs: observers)
    *obs = true;
```

Answer (score 5):

With C++0x (or rather C++11) range-based for loop, you can do the following:

```
for (auto& i : observers) {
   i = true;
}
```